# How can I have a camera orbit without using WebGLRenderer, and use canvas only?

Tags: three.js

I'm getting started with [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), and I don't want to use WebGLRenderer (`renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();`)  at all. Instead I want to use `renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();`.

I don't want to use `WebGLRenderer` due to lack of support.

How can I have a camera orbit without using WebGLRenderer, and use canvas only in three.js?

Comment: "Lack of support". Out of curiosity, are you targeting very old browsers, or old mobile devices?

Comment: @Paul-Jan I'm not targeting old browsers, but a lot of examples from the three.js.org, (like this one: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth) tells me "Your graphics card does not seem to support WebGL.
Find out how to get it here." Even though I have the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Ah, your *own machine* doesn't support it. That's a pretty good reason to go with canvas. :)

Comment: @Paul-Jan lol. Just tested it with firefox, and it words there, but doesn't work on chrome. I think I just  have to enable it. But if it's not enabled by my browser by default, why should it be enabled for others by default. The average user will not know how to enable it.

Comment: For most people, WebGL works fine (by default) in Chrome. Chrome has a specific blacklist for graphics cards that have been behaving problematic in the past, see https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists. It also sometimes has issues (e.g. after interrupted remote desktop sessions) where WebGL stops working until chrome restart. So yes, there are definitely people for who webGL is not an option, but do make sure not to be biased in your evaluation because you happen to fall in the group of outliers. See http://webglstats.com/ for stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three.js site has a small but effective set of Canvas samples as well. Just take a look at the source of https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_camera_orthographic: it has an orbiting camera. It is orthographic, which you might not want, but the source should be self-explanatory on how to change it to a perspective camera.